# How can i get the list of nested collection from firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Yes, I did go thru the other answers but my data is dynamic so I can't set a collection id.

This is the screenshot of the database [image]

Here, the main collection is `TRAINING_DATA` which has a document `CABIN_CREW` and then CABIN_CREW has a list of collections as seen in the screenshot,
I am trying to get the list

How can I do it?

This is all I could do as I do anything else gives me a null value.

```dart
 static Future<Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>>
      fetchTrainingData() async {
    print('fetching training data...  ');
    Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> result = {};

    final cabinCrewRefSnap = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('TRAINING_DATA')
        .doc('CABIN_CREW')
        .get();

    //get collection list names/id
   

    print(cabinCrewRefSnap);

    return {};
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can list the collections of a document using mobile and web clients. That is possible only with the Admin SDKs (Node.js, Python, Java, ...)  where you'll be able to find a [listCollections()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) function.

The best option that you have would be to maintain a list of collection names yourself. You can either store that list in Firestore, or in the Realtime Database. One thing to notice is when a new collection is added, then you have to add it to the list, and when is deleted, you have to delete it from the list.

Comment: okay! i see . thnx

Comment: In addition to the answer of my friend Alex here is a link to an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) dedicated on this subject, with code examples